# Jekyll broken after upgrading Ubuntu/Ruby

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, ruby, jekyll

I use Jekyll on my Ubuntu laptop. It worked with 15.10. I've upgraded to 16.04 and I got this error message :

```
$ jekyll -v
bash: /usr/local/bin/jekyll : /usr/bin/ruby2.1 : bad interpreter: no file or folder
```

Here is the installed version of Ruby :

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25) [i386-linux-gnu]
```

I've tried:

```
$ gem update jekyll
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
```

As `which ruby` returns `/usr/bin/ruby`, I've updated `/usr/local/bin/jekyll` changing `#!/usr/bin/ruby2.1` to `#!/usr/bin/ruby`.

Now I get :

```
$ jekyll -v
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in 'to_specs': Could not find 'jekyll' (>= 0) among 11 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/samuel/.gem/ruby/2.3.0:/var/lib/gems/2.3.0:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/rubygems-integration/2.3.0:/usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.3.0:/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all', execute 'gem env` for more information
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:328:in 'to_spec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in 'gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:22:in 'main'
```

Here is what `gem env` returns :

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.0 (2015-12-25 patchlevel 0) [i386-linux-gnu]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/samuel/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby2.3
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/samuel/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/2.3.0
     - /home/samuel/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
     - /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/rubygems-integration/2.3.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.3.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /snap/bin
```

Comment: What does `which ruby` say?

Comment: @edwinksl /usr/bin/ruby

Comment: How about `cat /usr/local/bin/jekyll`?

Comment: @edwinksl this : http://pastebin.com/tBriZuSX

Comment: Try changing the shebang line to `#!/usr/bin/ruby`. You will need `sudo` privileges to do this.

Comment: @edwinksl wouch http://pastebin.com/NLnQTiUJ

Comment: It looks like we managed to find `ruby` but it seems Jekyll is still broken in other ways. Can you update your question with what you did so far? Maybe others can figure out what else is wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue. It's caused by ruby update in new Ubuntu. Just uninstall jekyll and install it again:

```
gem uninstall jekyll
gem install jekyll
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the answer by @Piotr, I also had to uninstall and reinstall the gem `bundler`. That is, I ran,

```
gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler
bundle
```

Only after this did `bundle exec jekyll serve` start to work again after my upgrade from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.